# Loading label information from a QGIS syle file (.qml)?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.12

When my homebrewed style for road symbology and labeling is saved to a qml file, I am unable to load the labeling information from the qml file onto the same shapefile. This is the case for both the same map document and a new map document. The saved style loads but the labeling is blank. [Here](https://spideroak.com/share/OZQWYZLSNFSXI2DFMJWG63TEMU/sharedfiles_valerietheblonde/home/valerie/SpiderOak%20Hive/shared/roads.stackexchange.tar.gz) is a tar.gz with the roads shapefile, qml layer, and interstate symbol.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

### QGIS Info

QGIS version - 2.12.3-Lyon
Compiled against Qt 4.8.6 - Running against Qt 4.8.6
Compiled against GDAL/OGR 1.10.1 - Running against GDAL/OGR 1.10.1
Compiled against GEOS 3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 - Running against GEOS 3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921
PostgreSQL Client Version 9.4.4
SpatiaLite Version 4.1.1
QWT Version 6.0.0-svn
PROJ.4 Version 480
QScintilla2 Version 2.8.4

Comment: Oops. Your QML doesn't work because you missed the .dbf out of the tarball so your roads don't have any attributes...

Comment: I can't get QML to restore labelling settings either, even though the settings are written to the QML file. I think it works if you save the layer as a Layer Definition File and reload it... Bug? Possibly...

Comment: The shapefile didn't have a dbf file to begin with... Ok so, I saved the shapefile as another shapefile, it made a dbf file to go with it but the label styles still fail to load on this new shapefile.

Comment: Weird. The QML you bundled was clearly trying to do some styling based on attributes, it must have had one at some point!

Comment: You're right, @Spacedman! I saved the shapefile as a new shapefile, which added a dbf file. The qml was then able to load labeling information _just fine_. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug. Use the following workaround:

- Open the layer properties dialog
- Load the style
- **Cancel** the dialog

https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13667

Comment: That works for me. Note the style doesn't change at first so you might not think its worked, I have to update the map window (drag, zoom) and the new style (with labels) appears.

Comment: This workaround worked the first 2 times I tried it. Now it no longer works. As of now, there is no reliable workaround for this bug. None. Zero.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know copy and paste styles between different project files is the only workaround for this issue in QGIS 2.14.3. See also: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14224